# Pure JavaScript Carousel - restricting style.left value change to dynamic max value

Tags: javascript, html, carousel

I am creating a carousel from scratch using pure Javascript and require a pure Javascript solution, strictly no JQuery.

The html layout of the carousel with html & body etc removed is as follows;

carousel.php

```
<p class="ca_width"></p>
<p class="cw_width"></p>
<p class="cc_width"></p>
<p class="li_width"></p>
<p class="lftamount"></p>

<div class="box">


<div class="carousel">
    <div class="padding">

        <table class="pagination-container">
            <tr>
                <td class="left"><a class="pagination padding-small" onmouseover="carousel_left(this)">&#60;</a></td>
                <td class="right"><a class="pagination padding-small" onmouseover="carousel_right(this)">&#62;</a></td>
            <tr>
        </table>

        <div class="carousel-wrap clearfix">

            <ul class="carousel-container">

                <li><img src="http://21stcenturylovetriangle.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/sexy-woman.jpg?w=470"/></li><!--
                --><li><img src="http://gnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/wii-fit-fall-turns-british-woman-into-sex-addict-1.jpg"/></li><!--
                --><li><img src="http://healthyceleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/rosie_jones_sexy.jpg"/></li><!--
                --><li><img src="http://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/sexy-fit-women-7.jpg"/></li><!--
                --><li><img src="http://www.crazyleafdesign.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/31.jpg?ce0830"/></li><!--
                --><li><img src="http://www.crazyleafdesign.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/8.jpg?ce0830"/></li>

            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>


</div>
```

The css for the above html code is as follows;

carousel.css

```
*
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.box
{
    width:400px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;       
}

/*-----------------------------------*/

.carousel
{
    height:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:100px;
    border: solid thin;
    background: #F1F1F1;
}

.carousel-wrap
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    display:block;
    height:200px;
    border:solid thin;
    background:white;
}

.carousel-container
{
    list-style:none;
    height:200px;
    background:cyan;
    position:absolute;
}

.carousel-container li
{
    height:200px;
    //width:200px;
    background: red;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.carousel-container li img
{
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
}

/*-----------------------------------*/

.pagination-container
{
    width:100%;
}

.pagination-container tr
{
    width:100%;
}   

.pagination-container td
{
    width:50%;
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-left:8px;
    padding-right:8px;
}

.pagination
{
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height:25px;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background:black;
}

.left
{
    text-align:left;
}

.right
{
    text-align:right;
}

/*-----------------------------------*/

.padding
{
    padding:10px;
}

.padding-small
{
    padding:4px;
}
```

The Javascript for the carousel is as follows;

core.php

```
var ca_width; // Carousel width
var cw_width; // Carousel wrap width
var cc_width; // Carousel container width
var li_width; // Carousel container li width
var licount;  // Number of li in Carousel container

var i, obj, w;

window.onload = function () 
{
    var ca_obj = document.getElementsByClassName('carousel')[0];
    var cw_obj = document.getElementsByClassName('carousel-wrap')[0];
    var cc_obj = document.getElementsByClassName('carousel-container')[0];

    ca_width = ca_obj.offsetWidth; // Carousel width
    cw_width = cw_obj.offsetWidth; // Carousel wrap width
    cc_width = cc_obj.offsetWidth; // Carousel container width

    liobj = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-container li');

    for(i = 0; i < liobj.length;i++)
    {
        obj = liobj[i];
        obj.style.width = cw_width/2+"px";
    }

    li_width = liobj.item(0).offsetWidth;

    var style = getComputedStyle(cc_obj);
    var left = style.getPropertyValue("left");

    lftamount = left;

    document.getElementsByClassName('ca_width')[0].innerHTML = "Carousel Width: "+ca_width+"px";
    document.getElementsByClassName('cw_width')[0].innerHTML = "Carousel Wrap Width: "+cw_width+"px";
    document.getElementsByClassName('cc_width')[0].innerHTML = "Carousel Container Width: "+cc_width+"px";
    document.getElementsByClassName('li_width')[0].innerHTML = "Carousel Container li Width: "+li_width+"px";
    document.getElementsByClassName('lftamount')[0].innerHTML = "Carousel Container Left: "+lftamount;

}

function carousel_left(item) 
{
    var cc_obj = document.getElementsByClassName('carousel-container')[0];
    var style = getComputedStyle(cc_obj);
    var left = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left"));
    var newleft = left - li_width;

    for(i = left; i > newleft; i--)
    {
        cc_obj.style.left = i+"px";

        lftamount = left;
        document.getElementsByClassName('lftamount')[0].innerHTML = "Carousel Container Left: "+lftamount;

    }


}

function carousel_right(item)
{

    var cc_obj = document.getElementsByClassName('carousel-container')[0];
    var style = getComputedStyle(cc_obj);
    var left = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left"));
    var newleft = parseInt(left) + li_width;

    for(i = left; i < newleft; i++)
    {

        cc_obj.style.left = i+"px";

        lftamount = left;
        document.getElementsByClassName('lftamount')[0].innerHTML = "Carousel Container Left: "+lftamount;
    }
}
```

The carousel is a prototype, it is in the development phase of the development lifecycle.

The carousel works how I am expecting it to at this point, the problem I have is inside of the carousel_right() and carousel_left() functions.

carousel_left()

```
for(i = left; i > newleft; i--)
{
    cc_obj.style.left = i+"px";

    lftamount = left;
    document.getElementsByClassName('lftamount')[0].innerHTML = "Carousel Container Left: "+lftamount;

}
```

carousel_right()

```
for(i = left; i < newleft; i++)
{

    cc_obj.style.left = i+"px";       

    lftamount = left;
    document.getElementsByClassName('lftamount')[0].innerHTML = "Carousel Container Left: "+lftamount;
}
```

I wish to restrict the max style.left to stop the carousel-container ul moving too far to either side. So the style.left will stop adding once either the first image is in view or the last image is in view.

In other words I need to restrict the horizontal movement of the carousel-container ul based on its style.left value + or - which is based on the dynamic number of li in the carousel-container ul.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated, as for a JsFiddle, there is a version available http://jsfiddle.net/xxwatcherxx/m7amga08/5/ but I can't get the carousel_left() and carousel_right() functions to fire using jsFiddle. The carousel works fine on my development server, I dont use jsFiddle, sorry...

Theres also some CSS issues I need to sort out so the carousel-container ul is hidden behind the carousel-wrap div...if you know how to fix these issues then feel free to comment, Ill be fixing them myself but if someone else is thinking about using this code they may need help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little troubleshooting I managed to fix the double click bug, the fix is as follows;

```
//-------------------------
// Move right
function carousel_right() 
{
    var node = (cc.firstElementChild||cc.firstChild);
    cc.appendChild(node);
}

//-------------------------
// Move left
function carousel_left()
{
    var node = (cc.lastElementChild||cc.lastChild);
    cc.insertBefore(node, cc.childNodes[0]);
}
```

The double click bug can be replicated using the following function layout, the firstchild fails to populate the node variable until you second click;

```
//-------------------------
// Move right
function carousel_right() 
{
    var node = cc.firstChild;
    cc.appendChild(node);
}

//-------------------------
// Move left
function carousel_left()
{
     var node = cc.lastChild;
     cc.insertBefore(node, cc.childNodes[0]);
}
```

Now I have a carousel with pagination using 2 lines of code per function without restrictions and continuous... http://jsfiddle.net/xxwatcherxx/4tbyxk53/50/

With the fix in place there is no real difference between the two, in fact I would say the new transition functions work better than the previously tried functions...I personally prefer this two lined alternative than the 13 plus lines of code I started off with...the carousel_left() and carousel_right() functions use a simple pull and push method, take the first child from the front of the list and append to the back or take the last child and append to the front. The browser deals with the repositioning of the carousel items so the programmer doesn't have to.

Answer (score 1):

The Javascript for the carousel after minor changes is as follows;

core.php

```
var ca_width; // Carousel width
var cw_width; // Carousel wrap width
var cc_width; // Carousel container width
var li_width; // Carousel container li width

var currentStep=0;
var countSlides;

var i, obj, w;

window.onload = function () 
{
    var ca_obj = document.getElementsByClassName('carousel')[0];
    var cw_obj = document.getElementsByClassName('carousel-wrap')[0];
    var cc_obj = document.getElementsByClassName('carousel-container')[0];

    ca_width = ca_obj.offsetWidth; // Carousel width
    cw_width = cw_obj.offsetWidth; // Carousel wrap width
    cc_width = cc_obj.offsetWidth; // Carousel container width

    liobj = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-container li');

    for(i = 0; i < liobj.length;i++)
    {
        obj = liobj[i];
        obj.style.width = cw_width/2+"px";
    }

    li_width = liobj.item(0).offsetWidth;
    countSlides=liobj.length;

    var style = getComputedStyle(cc_obj);
    var left = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left"));

    lftamount = left;

    document.getElementsByClassName('ca_width')[0].innerHTML = "Carousel Width: "+ca_width+"px";
    document.getElementsByClassName('cw_width')[0].innerHTML = "Carousel Wrap Width: "+cw_width+"px";
    document.getElementsByClassName('cc_width')[0].innerHTML = "Carousel Container Width: "+cc_width+"px";
    document.getElementsByClassName('li_width')[0].innerHTML = "Carousel Container li Width: "+li_width+"px";
    document.getElementsByClassName('lftamount')[0].innerHTML = "Carousel Container Left: "+lftamount+"px";

};

function carousel_left(item) 
{
    if(currentStep<=2-countSlides) return;
    currentStep--;

    var cc_obj = document.getElementsByClassName('carousel-container')[0];
    var style = getComputedStyle(cc_obj);
    var left = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left"));
    var newleft = left - li_width;

    cc_obj.style.left = newleft+"px";


    lftamount = left;
    document.getElementsByClassName('lftamount')[0].innerHTML = "Carousel Container Left: "+lftamount+"px";
    cc_width = cc_obj.offsetWidth;
    document.getElementsByClassName('cc_width')[0].innerHTML = "Carousel Container Width: "+cc_width+"px";

}

function carousel_right(item)
{
    if(currentStep>=0) return;
    currentStep++;

    var cc_obj = document.getElementsByClassName('carousel-container')[0];
    var style = getComputedStyle(cc_obj);
    var left = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left"));
    var newleft = left + li_width;

    cc_obj.style.left = newleft+"px";

    lftamount = left;
    document.getElementsByClassName('lftamount')[0].innerHTML = "Carousel Container Left: "+lftamount+"px";
    cc_width = cc_obj.offsetWidth;
    document.getElementsByClassName('cc_width')[0].innerHTML = "Carousel Container Width: "+cc_width+"px";   

}
```

I removed the for loops in carousel_left() and carousel_right() because it was causing alignment issues, so the carousel_left() and carousel_right() functions ended up as follows;

carousel_left()

```
function carousel_left(item) 
{
    if(currentStep<=2-countSlides) return;
    currentStep--;

    var cc_obj = document.getElementsByClassName('carousel-container')[0];
    var style = getComputedStyle(cc_obj);
    var left = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left"));
    var newleft = left - li_width;

    cc_obj.style.left = newleft+"px";

}
```

carousel_right()

```
function carousel_right(item)
{
    if(currentStep>=0) return;
    currentStep++;

    var cc_obj = document.getElementsByClassName('carousel-container')[0];
    var style = getComputedStyle(cc_obj);
    var left = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left"));
    var newleft = left + li_width;

    cc_obj.style.left = newleft+"px";

}
```

Using this Javascript everything lines up once the carousel-container ul is moved left and right...it is nearly a complete extremely simple carousel...in the above example I've simply stripped out the parts which update the output tags on carousel.php for debugging to make it simple to read with only the main parts required.

This code should give someone the start of a bare bones carousel without JQuery, if you want to build your own from scratch...

[image]

Heres a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xxwatcherxx/m7amga08/11/ although like I mentioned earlier the carousel_left() and carousel_right() functions don't fire in jsFiddle but it works on a development server away from jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

add two global variables:

```
var currentStep=0;
var countSlides=liobj.length;
```

in function **carousel_left** add this code on begin:

```
if(currentStep<=2-countSlides) return;
currentStep--;
```

in function **carousel_right** add this code on begin:

```
if(currentStep>=0) return;
currentStep++;
```

**EDIT CSS fix** - add this style:

```
.carousel-wrap {overflow: hidden;  position: relative;}
.carousel-container {width: 5000px;} //or greater
```

Comment: Let me give it a go and Ill update you with the result...I don't know if it was just too late, but I couldn't see what I needed to do...thank you so much for replying...

Comment: You sir/madam are the savior...if you were a super hero, you would be flash gordon https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MS4_Z84-rRE I owe you a pint...if you have a donate button give me the link and Ill buy you a pint when I get paid...

Comment: I added the 2 global variables like you said var currentStep=0;
var countSlides; then added countSlides=liobj.length; in the onload function...thank you so so much ;) high five and a good day to you, you genius you ;)

Comment: An updated jsFiddle with the added fix by dm4web (flash gordon) http://jsfiddle.net/xxwatcherxx/m7amga08/6/ although I still can't get the jsFiddle to fire, those with jsFiddle knowledge will get it to work...it will work on a development server if a person takes the code it can be reused, edited, updated etc...it works as a simple carousel...just the css to play about with to hide the carousel-container ul behind the carousel-wrap...but for those trying to build their own it may help in some way or another...cheers again and again dm4web...

Comment: For anyone viewing this page and thinking about using the code then you probably want to change the onmouseover="" to a onclick="" event, works better, the onmouseover="" can be a little glitchy. For human computer interaction purposes the onmouseover="" is a little irritating in my opinion, the onclick="" gives it a better feel...

Comment: tnx :) check EDIT in my answer for css fix (ui hidden)

Answer (score 0):

One thing I think I should mention to people setting out on the adventure of DIY carousel is a highlight bug which I have no fix for currently although I am working on it...when you scroll the carousel every now and then the images are highlighted as below;

[image]

This doesn't happen always only sometimes...it is important to point out so people know what kind of issues to expect when setting out on a DIY project...

Comment: dm4web's fix for this bug is with the following css applied to the carousel div -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none;

Answer (score 0):

I've actually managed to implement a better way to carousel and got the carousel_left() and carousel_right() functions to work using 2 lines of code, which I think is pretty impressive and I don't have to implement any restrictions on the carousel...

```
//-------------------------
// Move right
function carousel_right() 
{
    var node = cc.firstChild;
    cc.appendChild(node);
}

//-------------------------
// Move left
function carousel_left()
{
     var node = cc.lastChild;
     cc.insertBefore(node, cc.childNodes[0]);
}
```

It is a little different responsively but it works just as well, a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xxwatcherxx/4tbyxk53/45/.

** One thing to note is that we noticed a double click bug with this method...the pagination event fires but doesn't run the called function unless you use a double click **

Comment: Autoplay with updated carousel_left() and carousel_right() functions http://jsfiddle.net/xxwatcherxx/4tbyxk53/48

Answer (score 0):

What we found through testing is that the functions provided below carousel_left() and carousel_right() although not currently perfect, they work better than the functions carousel_left() and carousel_right() mentioned above http://jsfiddle.net/xxwatcherxx/4tbyxk53/49/ http://jsfiddle.net/xxwatcherxx/4tbyxk53/45/ in that they only require one mouse click, the below functions are faster than the ones above and the functions above require 2 mouse clicks, always failing to call the script on the first click - I am looking in to why this is happening I have no answers at this moment in time. If the functions above worked with a single mouse click then I would prefer the above functions although slightly slower I do prefer them for the process that takes place.

```
//-------------------------
// Move right
function carousel_right() 
{
    if(ccli_position<=2-ccli_total) 
    {
        cc_newleft = 0;
        cc.style.left = cc_newleft+"px";
        ccli_position = (2-ccli_total)+(ccli_total-2);
        return;
    }
    ccli_position--;

    var cc_newleft;

    cc_cs = getComputedStyle(cc);
    cc_left = parseInt(cc_cs.getPropertyValue("left"));
    cc_newleft = cc_left - ccli_width;

    cc.style.left = cc_newleft+"px";
}

//-------------------------
// Move left
function carousel_left()
{
    if(ccli_position>=0)
    {
        cc_cs = getComputedStyle(cc);
        cc_left = parseInt(cc_cs.getPropertyValue("left"));
        cc_newleft = cc_left - (ccli_width * (ccli_total-2));
        cc.style.left = cc_newleft+"px";
        ccli_position = 2-ccli_total;
        return;
    }
    ccli_position++;

    var cc_newleft;

    cc_cs = getComputedStyle(cc);
    cc_left = parseInt(cc_cs.getPropertyValue("left"));
    cc_newleft = cc_left + ccli_width;

    cc.style.left = cc_newleft+"px";
}
```